# How to Convert Integer to int in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Suppose i have Method written in Java script in GWT(JSNI) which accept the wrapper data type Integer and i need to convert into Primitive Data type inside JS.

```
    public static native void nativeMethod(Integer index)/*-{
// how to check the null values
//how to convert into primitive type

}-*/;
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Java or Javascript? Hotdog or dog? #facepalm

Comment: @Raptor i think you meant **hotdog** or **hot dog**...

Comment: @Raptor Apparently GWT uses native methods as a bridge between Java and JavaScript, instead of Java and C. Strange, but I don't know anything about GWT so maybe it's not strange.

Comment: Yeah, I answered for both because GWT lets you do most of your coding in Java and produces JavaScript/HTML/CSS. So I don't know where the OP needs to do the conversion. :-)

Comment: just i need the conversion in Java script ,which convert into primitive type from wrapper(object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static native void nativeMethod(Integer index)/*-{
var converted 
if(index!=null){
    converted = Number(hindeIndex);
    }else{
    converted=null;
    }
}-*/;
```

This Worked..
Had a null check,if not then convert it into var type

Answer (score 2):

```
public static native void nativeMethod(Integer index)/*-{
  if (index == null) {
    // well, index is null…
  } else {
    var i = index.@java.lang.Integer::intValue()();
    // now 'i' is the int value of 'index'
  }
}-*/;
```